# In SQL Server Convert a Recursive CTE to a Function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-function

In SQL Server 2008 R2, in a stored procedure I have 2 `DECLARE` and a recursive CTE in a script:

```
DECLARE @MaxActivityDate DATETIME = (SELECT MAX(ActivityDate) FROM tbl)
DECLARE @MinActivityDate DATETIME = (SELECT MIN(ActivityDate) FROM tbl)

-- Generate all the dates between the minimum and the maximum
WITH DateRange (DateValue) AS
(
     SELECT @MinActivityDate DateValue
     UNION ALL
         SELECT DateValue + 1
         FROM DateRange
         WHERE DateValue + 1 <= @MaxActivityDate
)

SELECT DateValue
FROM DateRange
[...]
```

I now need to use this code in another stored procedure. I don't want any code duplication. How can I convert this into a function to use in both scripts?

Comment: Be careful when turning this into a function - it is "hiding" the fact that there's a database access in this function, and calling this code repeatedly inside a larger `SELECT` (returning a large number of rows) could cause horribly bad performance.

Comment: I've hidden some code from the question (to simplify the question) that adjusts the MIN, MAX numbers so that they're never 1 year apart.

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2800/sql-server-function-to-return-a-range-of-dates/

Answer (score 2):

Be very careful with this type of cte. It is hidden RBAR all its own, even without being part of a larger query. This is the same issue as using a cte to count. Here is an awesome article explaining this issue. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

For a better approach you should use a tally table. Here is one such article that goes deeper into this technique. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Here is a set based inline table valued function for doing this kind of thing.

```
create function GetDateRange
(
    @MinActivityDate datetime
    , @MaxActivityDate DATETIME
) RETURNS TABLE AS
    RETURN

    WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )

    select DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, @MinActivityDate) as DateValue
    from cteTally t
    where t.N <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinActivityDate, @MaxActivityDate)
```

Now using this is super simple. Here is one way you could use this in your current example.

```
select dr.DateValue
from GetDateRange(myDate.MinDate, myDate.MaxDate) dr
cross apply 
(
    select MIN(ActivityDate) as MinDate
        , MAX(ActivityDate) as MaxDate
    from tbl
) myDate
```